# #sidebar position:fixed at certain scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please look at this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDFpq.png

My aim is to have the sidebar as it is in the diagram but once it reaches the top of the window (when the user scrolls down), it changes to `position:fixed` and changes `margin-top:0`. I've looked at a tutorial online to this and learned that `position:absolute` may be useful but I have honestly no clue how to do this so any help would be useful. If you need a bit more detail on what I mean because you don't understand that please do ask :)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We need a bit more detail on what you mean.

Comment: He wants the sidebar to get sticky as soon as the logo is scrolled out of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect when it reaches the top of the window, you can use the window.scroll event.

Here's a nice tutorial that teaches you exactly what you want to do:
http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

Answer (score 1):

Your **sidebar** will have a variable height until the **logo** is scrolled out of sight. Instead of using `position:absolute`, keep it at `position:fixed`, check the remaining height of the **logo** and extract this from the **sidebar**'s height.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2afv13z3/

When keeping the **sidebar** at `bottom:0;` and top property based on the window scroll position, you'll always have it at 100% under your **logo**.